# Find the maximum value a product

Tags: algebra-precalculus, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

Three positive integers their sum is 90, find the numbers for which their product is maximum.
Let the numbers $x,y$ and $z$
we have
$$x+y+z=90$$
Using AM-GM 
$$x+y+z\ge 3(xyz)^{\frac{1}{3}}$$
then
$$xyz\le2700$$
then 
$$xyz=2700$$
Now we have two equations and 3 unknowns can we find those numbers using these two equations ?

Comment: check for 2700, it should be $30^3=27'000$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINT**

Recall that for AM-GM equality holds for $x=y=z$.

Answer (score 0):

You already have their maximum product, it's 27000. You know that they can achieve this value because the AM-GM has an equality case: when all variables are equal, i.e. $x=y=z$. So you are looking for three equal numbers $x,y,z$ adding up to 90, therefore they are $30$.

Answer (score 0):

AM-GM inequality becomes equality if and only if $x=y=z$, so $3x=90$, $x=y=z=30$ and we really have $x+y+z=90=3\sqrt[3]{30\cdot 30\cdot 30}$.